# vprintf like function but that takes a string ID

Tags: c++, mfc

I need something very similar but with a change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void WriteFormatted ( const char * format, ... )
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  vprintf (format, args);
  va_end (args);
}

int main ()
{
   WriteFormatted ("Call with %d variable argument.\n",1);

   return 0;
}
```

What I want different in above is that the first parameter is a string id(an `int`). The function will then load the corresponding string to that id and apply the formatting. Is it possible in a good way?

So my proposed function signature will become like the following but then using it doesn't quite make sense because the 2nd parameter has to be a string.

```
void WriteFormatted3(int stringId, const char * format, ...)
{
    // for demo, assume the following string corresponds to the stringId (hardcoded for this demo)
    // just we can we run this without LoadString() id in a simple console application
    char * str = "assume the id passed %d correspond to this string";

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(str, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main ()
{
   WriteFormatted (STRING_ID_ONE_ARGUMENT, "1"); // 1 has to be string or it will not compile

   return 0;
}
```

**Update/justifcation**

I could always load the string first from the id and then call that original WriteFormatted() function but the reason I don't want to do that is I am refactoring code and this call is a lot of places. So I want to pass the string id and let the function load that string instead of me calling it every place.

Comment: So how are these Id;s and strings stored?

Comment: @Elemental its resource string. Basicall you load it with LoadString(id) function. This part is very straightforward.

Comment: I don;t get why you think you need the second parameter to be a string.

Comment: What's wrong with: `void WriteFormatted ( int stringId, ... )`? If you refactor, do it properly.

Comment: "using it doesn't quite make sense because the 2nd parameter has to be a string." Why??? Why has is to be a string?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage the `format`-string as a resource, then I'd suggest to rewrite the code as follows. I suppose that `LoadString` returns an `std::string`; if not, adjust the code accordingly. Note that it does not make to much sense to provide both, an ID representing a format and a format: which one would you then pass to `vprintf`?. Hope it helps.

```
void WriteFormatted (int stringId formatId, ... )
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, formatId);
  std::string formatStr = LoadString(formatId);
  const char* format = formatStr.c_str();
  vprintf (format, args);
  va_end (args);
}

int main ()
{
   WriteFormatted (STRING_ID_ONE_ARGUMENT, 1);

   return 0;
}
```